# Prove $\exists (u,v) \in \mathbb{Z}_n \times \mathbb{Z}_n$ st every element equals $k_1(a,b) + k_2(u,v)$

Tags: linear-algebra, number-theory, finite-groups, cyclic-groups

Suppose $(a,b) \in \mathbb{Z}_n \times \mathbb{Z}_n$ has order $n$.

Prove that there exists $(u,v) \in \mathbb{Z}_n \times \mathbb{Z}_n$ such that every element of $\mathbb{Z}_n \times \mathbb{Z}_n$ equals $k_1(a,b) + k_2(u,v)$ for some $k_1, k_2 \in \mathbb{Z}$.

This is final part of question I [asked earlier.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2733442/prove-that-there-exist-r-s-in-mathbbz-such-that-det-beginpmatrix-a?noredirect=1#comment5641269_2733442)

I know very little linear algebra, so i'm not sure how to go about proving that $(a,b)$ and $(u,v)$ form a basis for $\mathbb{Z}_n \times \mathbb{Z}_n$ any direction or help would be greatly appreciated, thaks

Comment: I think $(u, v)=(1, 0)$ would work if $b\neq 0$. If $b=0$, then $(u, v)=(0, 1)$ certainly work.

Comment: It won't be a vector space unless $n$ is prime. When $n$ isn't prime, what you have is a $\Bbb{Z}$ - or $\Bbb{Z}_n$ -module.

Comment: @See-WooLee Not really, for example for $n=6$ and $(a,b)=(2,3)$ you see that $(1,0)$ does not work (because the second coordinate in the combination is always $0$ or $3$). Analogously $(0,1)$ does not work. But $(1,1)$ does.

Answer (score 0):

Since $(a, b)$ has order $n$, $\gcd (a, b, n) = 1$. In general, if $\gcd (a, b, n) = d$ then the order of $(a, b)$ is at most $n/d$ (in fact equal but we don't need this) since $n$ divides $(n/d) \cdot (a, b)$.

Thus there are integers $x, y, z$ such that $ax + by + nz = 1$. Now we can take $(u, v) = (-y, x)$. One way to see this is to reinterpret $ax + by = 1 \pmod{n}$ as computing the determinant of the matrix
$$\begin{bmatrix} a & -y\\ b & x \end{bmatrix}$$
over $\mathbb{Z}/n$. Or we could just use the inverse directly, for any $(p, q)$:
$(p, q) = (px + qy) \cdot (a, b) + (aq - bp) \cdot (-y, x) \pmod{n}$ .